# Vim: multiline search for Aaaa some garbage Bbbb but not with Cccc in between

Tags: regex, vim, regex-lookarounds

I have to analyze a log file and I am looking for repeated patterns, for example i want to find:

```
Start ... 
some lines ... 
Start ...
```

So for this I am using

```
/Start\_.\{-}Start
```

but unfortunately in finds also this, which I want to avoid:

```
Start ... 
End ... 
Start ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with `Start\(\_.\(End\)\@!\)\{-}Start`.

I've basically just changed your `\_.` to something more complex, namely `\(\_.\(End\)\@!\)`, which matches `\_.` where `End` does *not* match.

You can even enforce that the `End` must be at the beginning of the line for it to prevent the match, by just changing `End` to `^End` in the regex above.

Notice, however, that if you truly have the same word for opening and closing the group you want to match, then the regex will match even between groups. For instance, in this

```
Start ... here
some lines ...
Start ... here


Start ... here
not End...
Start ... here


Start ...
End...
Start ...
```

the regex `Start\(\_.\(^End\)\@!\)\{-}Start` will match on the four lines marked as `here`.

So if you can write a regex `re1` which only matches the opening, one regex `re3` that matches only the closing, and one regex `re2` that matches what you don't want to match, then you can combine the into `re1\(\_.\(re2\)\@!\)\{-}re3`.

---

A deleted answer by [Andreas Louv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/887539/andreas-louv) used `\%(…\)` instead of `\(…\)`. As you can see in `:help E53`,

- that's for not counting it as a subexpression (i.e. successive `\(`s correspond to `\n` for increasing *`n`*, but `\%(`s don't have a corresponding number through which you can refer to them;
- and it's a little bit faster.

Comment: I think you posted your answer just a few seconds before mine. As they are essential the same, one might as well be deleted.

Comment: @AndreasLouv, thanks. I've added some additional info from your answer. Worth learning for whoever really likes Vim and regex ;)